# Footer disappear when adding position fixed

Tags: html, css

I made a simple page with a fixed footer on the bottom.

The final result I want to achieve is like this https://www.sallyhart.photography/#

[You can see my codepen here >>](https://codepen.io/KT-Lin/pen/drJzGd?editors=1100)

```
footer {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -40px;
  left: 40px;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}
```

```css
/*-- Global--*/
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
       box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

@import @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One');

/*-- Title --*/
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  left: 40px;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color : white;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
  left: 40px;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  color : white;
}

footer {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -40px;
  left: 40px;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}

footer a {
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-decoration: initial;
  color: white;
}


/*-- Image section--*/

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


section.first {
  background-image:url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552394459-917cbbffbc84?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

section.second {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552426948-96ed4eb0509c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1955&q=80");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

section.third {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551030973-c739c33a78bc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1921&q=80");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}


section.fourth {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552403709-27a46aab46de?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1570&q=80");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

section.fourth {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1551337213-0b69f29206e7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

section.fifth {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1551337213-0b69f29206e7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

section.sixth {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550668180-3205f7bb6a9e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2850&q=80");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Sally Hart</h1>
  <p>Photographer and designer</p>
</header>


<section class="first"></section>
<section class="second"></section>
<section class="third"></section>
<section class="fourth"></section>
<section class="fifth"></section>
<section class="sixth"></section>

<footer>
  <a href="#">Email</a>
  <a href="#">Twitter</a>
  <a href="#">Instagram</a>
</footer>
```

I want to make the footer sticked on the bottom and always shows up on the bottom left corner when scrolling the web page, right now it didn't show up on the first page, only on top of the last image when you scroll to the bottom it shows up.

When I added position:fixed to css the whole footer somehow disappear.

Can anyone please help me with solving this issue?

Many thanks ! :-)

Comment: when adding *fixed positioning*, add `bottom: 0` and change `margin-top: -40px` to `margin-bottom: 40px`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `position` of the footer to `fixed`. Remove `margin-top` and add `bottom: 0;` (or whatever distance from the very bottom of the screen you want.).

```
footer {
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 40px;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: It works thanks a lot :-))) My first question on stackoverflow, it's amazing here!

Answer (score 1):

`footer` should be like this:

```
footer {
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 40px;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}
```

So, `bottom: 20px` and `fixed`.

Comment: It works thanks a lot guys :-))) My first question on stackoverflow, it's amazing here!

Answer (score 1):

Position it fixed instead of absolute.

```
footer { position: fixed; bottom: 40px; left: 40px; }
```

Comment: It works thanks a lot :-))) My first question on stackoverflow, it's amazing here!